Angular SSR - How to avoid caching sensitive data
According to Angular, SSR will cache HttpClient GET calls:

When SSR is enabled, HttpClient responses are cached while running on the server. After that this information is serialized and transferred to a browser as a part of the initial HTML sent from the server. In a browser, HttpClient checks whether it has data in the cache and if so, reuses it instead of making a new HTTP request during initial application rendering. HttpClient stops using the cache once an application becomes stable while running in a browser.

How do we ensure that authenticated endpoints are not cached? For example, what is the risk of one user's API calls with an auth token being cached on the server-side and returned to other users?

We can customize the transferCache with the provider withHttpTransferCacheOptions which has an input object HttpTransferCacheOptions with the below properties.
type HttpTransferCacheOptions = {
    includeHeaders?: string[];
    filter?: (req: HttpRequest<unknown>) => boolean;
    includePostRequests?: boolean;
};

So we can use the filter property to filter out routes which we want to filter
Angular Github Code
/**
 * Options to configure how TransferCache should be used to cache requests made via HttpClient.
 *
 * @param includeHeaders Specifies which headers should be included into cached responses. No
 *     headers are included by default.
 * @param filter A function that receives a request as an argument and returns a boolean to indicate
 *     whether a request should be included into the cache.
 * @param includePostRequests Enables caching for POST requests. By default, only GET and HEAD
 *     requests are cached. This option can be enabled if POST requests are used to retrieve data
 *     (for example using GraphQL).
 * @param includeRequestsWithAuthHeaders Enables caching of requests containing either `Authorization`
 *     or `Proxy-Authorization` headers. By default, these requests are excluded from caching.
 *
 * @publicApi
 */
export type HttpTransferCacheOptions = {
  includeHeaders?: string[];
  filter?: (req: HttpRequest<unknown>) => boolean;
  includePostRequests?: boolean;
  includeRequestsWithAuthHeaders?: boolean;
};

Final code:
...
provideClientHydration(
    withHttpTransferCacheOptions({
        filter: req => !req.url.startsWith('https://internal')
    })
);
...

